# If matter cannot be destroyed, does that mean that these particles are created somewhere else after breakdown but in the particles original shape?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, mass-energy

In the electron collider, after the breakdown into smaller particles, these particles last for a fraction of a second, and then they disappear.

**My question is:**

If matter cannot be destroyed, does that mean that these particles are created somewhere else after breakdown but in the particles original shape?

Comment: Matter can be destroyed (or rather: converted to and from energy).  That's perhaps the single most important discovery in 20th century physics.

Comment: May I ask: who told you that matter can not be destroyed?

Comment: that is why i am asking.. :)  is the answer  YES the particle is destroyed?  But whats with that thing that mater exists at the same time at many places?   exactly that particle that was destroyed.

Comment: @Qmechanic    i dont want to bother, my be my English was not quite well so you my be did not notice what i had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

The 'rule' that *"matter can not be [created or] destroyed"* simply isn't true.

Matter *can* be created and destroyed under the right circumstances, it's just that those circumstances are not met for macroscopic quantities of matter in places where humans live. This means that the conservation of matter can be taken as true in almost all of chemistry and large parts of physics as well as all of everyday life, but should be understood to be approximate.

The 'law' of conservation of matter has been subsumed by the law of conservation of energy through the usual relationship $E = mc^2$ (or more properly combined with the kinetic energy as $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$ so that it covers massless as well as massive particles), and we have some additional conservation laws for Baryon number, and total Lepton (both which may also be approximate symmetries).